# How to learn composition when dealing with products or videogame graphics?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, composition

apologize if this can be easily googled or was answered before, I could not find anything. Most composition is how to frame your picture.

I am frequently preparing images for my articles and need to compose either few products on a single image (for example new laptops) or screenshots from games. Are there some general guidelines how to go about this? Or some cool techniques that are not obvious?

From my point of view, my compositions look very lame.

Thanks, if something is not clear I'll be happy to provide more info

EDIT: Sorry guys, here are some examples what I meant:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zes1d.jpg

This is the size I need to use most of the time. Usually I have a lot of assets in PNG from different angles.

Comment: Giving recommendations about improvement is hard without knowing what you have so far. Why not include some example images?

Comment: What is obvious to me is not obvious to you (sic)! So context needed.

Comment: @joojaa sorry, added example images

Comment: @rapidograph sorry, example images added

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. However there's a couple of things, I think the first example is almost too complex. A lot of detail, strange background image and the yellow doesn't quite fit with that gold.

I suggest using an image that is appropriate for the target audience. If you look on Amazon for laptops or monitors you can see that typically a gaming monitor will have a game snapshot (or something that looks like a game snapshot) an IPS monitor will have a very high contrast background image or using video editing software, and a simple everyday laptop will usually be watching a video of sorts. And even just the simple windows 10 and simple start menu.

There isn't really any particular composition needed and I think you're overthinking it too much! If you want it to look real than I suggest adding a screen shine or using a real scene like this: http://www.freepik.com/free-psd/laptop-mock-up_944602.htm

I hope this answers your question!

EDIT: oh, and in regards to correct composition of an image, Keep things simple. This isn't much different from understanding correct composition of a photograph. I suggest looking at the Golden Ratio for design or rule of thirds.